# Linux / Python / problem with virtual environments

Tags: python, linux-mint, python-venv

i have an actual Linux Mint distribution and tried to upgrade to python 3.9 - so far i think the installation has worked:

```
rapid1898@rapid1898-B85-HD3:~/DEV/TEST$ python3
Python 3.9.4 (default, Apr  7 2021, 21:52:34) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

But my problem is that i am not able to install a virtual environment with 3.9.4. - i get this error

```
    rapid1898@rapid1898-B85-HD3:~/DEV/TEST$ python3 -m venv TEST2
    Error: Command '['/home/rapid1898/DEV/TEST/TEST2/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Interestingly when i am doing the following it works - BUT then this virutal environment hast Python 3.6. and not 3.9...

```
rapid1898@rapid1898-B85-HD3:~/DEV$ virtualenv -p python3 TEST
created virtual environment CPython3.6.9.final.0-64 in 172ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/rapid1898/DEV/TEST, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/rapid1898/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==21.0.1, setuptools==54.1.2, wheel==0.36.2
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
```

Several times i did - but this seems not to help - the error message keeps the same

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-venv
```

Any idea what i can do to get an venv with Python 3.9?

Comment: can you try with `python3.9` not with `python3`?

Comment: Yes thanks - with that is was working.

python3.9 -m venv TEST2